# Polymer component template minification

Tags: polymer, minify, polymer-cli, polymer-3.x

I'm looking for a way to minify the white space in template literals. Since regular js minification wouldn't remove white space on a template literal I was expecting that maybe `polymer-cli` had a way to minify those.

An example of the result of minification:

```
import{PolymerElement,html}from'../node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';export default class MyApp extends PolymerElement{static get is(){return'my-app'}static get template(){return html`
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
          height: 100vh;
        }

        .app {
          height: 100vh;
        }
      </style>
      <div class="app">
        My App
      </div>
    `}}customElements.define(MyApp.is,MyApp);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`polymer-cli` currently doesn't support minification of tagged template strings. Internally, it uses Babel plugins to minify JavaScript, so ideally we'd be able to insert the [`babel-plugin-minify-template-strings`](https://github.com/DanielWhiteCerner/babel-plugin-minify-template-strings) plugin into the pipeline when [minification is enabled](https://github.com/Polymer/tools/blob/8ee9f7f/packages/build/src/js-transform.ts#L196-L200).

For now, we could use `babel-cli` along with that plugin to process the build output of `polymer-cli`:

1. Start with a Polymer 3 template project, e.g., [`PolymerLabs/start-polymer3`](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/start-polymer3).

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/PolymerLabs/start-polymer3.git
   cd start-polymer3
   ```
2. Install `babel-cli` and the `babel-plugin-minify-template-strings` plugin. Your project may need other Babel plugins. In this case, this template project needs [`babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/) for Babel to handle the dynamic imports in the code.

   ```
   yarn add -D babel-cli \
               babel-plugin-minify-template-strings \
               babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
   ```
3. Add a `.babelrc` config file with the following file contents:

   ```
   {
     "compact": true,
     "ignore": [
       "node_modules"
     ],
     "plugins": [
       "minify-template-strings",
       "syntax-dynamic-import"
     ]
   }
   ```
4. Add a `build` NPM script to `package.json` to run `babel-cli` (with `.babelrc` above) on the JavaScript output of `polymer build`:

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "build": "polymer build && $(npm bin)/babel -d . build/**/src/**/*.js"
   }
   ```
5. Run `npm run build` (or `yarn build`). The command output (running with `polymer-cli (1.7.0-pre.13)`, `zsh`, macOS High Sierra) should look similar to this:

   ```
   ➜  start-polymer3 git:(master) ✗ yarn build
   yarn run v1.3.2
   $ polymer build && $(npm bin)/babel -d . build/**/src/**/*.js
   info: [cli.command.build]    Clearing build/ directory...
   info: [cli.build.build]    (es6-unbundled) Building...
   info: [cli.build.build]    (es6-unbundled) Build complete!
   build/es6-unbundled/src/lazy-element.js -> build/es6-unbundled/src/lazy-element.js
   build/es6-unbundled/src/start-polymer3.js -> build/es6-unbundled/src/start-polymer3.js
   ✨  Done in 8.66s.
   ➜  start-polymer3 git:(master) ✗
   ```

*See [GitHub repo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/start-polymer3/tree/minify-tagged-template-strings) with the above changes, and its [sample output](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/start-polymer3/blob/c9a0848/build/es6-unbundled/src/start-polymer3.js)*

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to setup your `polymer.json` with the following config?:

```
"builds": [{
  "bundle": true,
  "js": {"minify": true},
  "css": {"minify": true},
  "html": {"minify": true}
}],
```